# ruby socket log server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

We use the default ruby logging module to log the errors. We use the delayed_job which is using many worker processes. So we could not manage the log files.

We need the ruby based log server with rolling file appender and archive facility so that we can push the logs to the log server and let the log server to manage the logging task.

Do we have ruby based solution or other recommended solutions to manage this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Ruby's syslog in the standard library? Normally the docs are non-existent, but the Rails docs seem to cover it, kinda. http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/syslog/rdoc/index.html

Otherwise you can find out some info by looking through the syslog files themselves and reading http://glu.ttono.us/articles/2007/07/25/ruby-syslog-readme which is what I did when I started using it.

You don't say what OS you are on, but Mac OS and Linux have a very powerful syslog built in, which Ruby's syslog piggybacks on so you should be able to send to the system's syslog and have it split out your stream, roll the files, forward them, and do lots of other stuff with them.